# Create database and table syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am failing to find an example of creating the database and a table in one script. I am not sure how to do this because I have no `MySQL` installed. This is what I have:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;

USE TestDB;

CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Is this valid for `MySQL`? I tried to test this on http://rextester.com/ but getting exception:

> Access denied for user 'rextester_user'@'localhost' to database
>   'testdb'

Edit:

What is going on? So simple question without answer?! Can anynbody just copy and paste this code to `MySQL` to verify it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that site. Does it give users the ability to create databases?

Comment: you need to grant access rights to the user

Comment: try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'rextester_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: @Aris, it would be great if you can manage to tell in details in the answer format!

Comment: I believe this is for MSSQL, not MySQL.

Comment: @Auguste, actually it will work for both, but there is no schema part, so it should work on MySQL.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, thanks but it seems that that site denies that feature. I am getting the same. Tried before create database and after it.

Comment: it might just be me, but reading the documentation for an extremely popular and well documented thing like `mysql` is where I would start, but then again, I am not as lazy or trusting to rely on random internet people to do my work for me without understanding what they are saying and being able to independently verify it.

Comment: rextester doesn't allow creating new databases. There is just one database 'rextester' which you should try scripts against

Answer (score 0):

This should work, providing you run it with a user who has permission to grant permission...

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'youruser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

USE TestDB;

CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```